# Assembly IA32: What's wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: assembly, x86

Anyone could help me on this piece of code? 
In this case I want to use the value pointed by ptrgrades and then multiply by 4(array of integers) to increment the correspondent value in ptrfreq(array with absolute frequencies) to update that value. 
But I think that I'm having some problems to get the correct address value to use in %edi register or maybe %eax value.

```
    movl    ptrgrades, %esi         # set esi pointer to grades
    movl    grades_length, %ecx     # length of vector grades
l_freq:
    movl    ptrfreq, %edi           # reset with inital addrs of pointer
    movl    (%esi), %eax            # tmp = grades[i]
    shll    $2, %eax                 # multiply grade by 4
    addl    %eax, %edi              # and add to the ptrfreq addrs
    incl    (%edi)                  # freq[i]++
    addl    $4, (%esi)               # ptrgrade++
    loop    l_freq                  # loop while ecx != 0
```

Comment: Try `addl $4, %esi` instead of `addl $4, (%esi)`. While the latter does `grades[i] += 4;`, the former does `grades += 4;`, or, if `grades` is a `int *`, `++grades;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> addl    $4, (%esi)               # ptrgrade++
> ```

To correct your program (and have the comment reflect the code), you want to increase the `%esi` register and not the memory where `%esi` points to. Write this:

```
addl    $4, %esi                 # ptrgrade++
```

---

> ```
> shll    $2, %eax                 # multiply grade by 4
> addl    %eax, %edi              # and add to the ptrfreq addrs
> incl    (%edi)                  # freq[i]++
> ```

This trio of instructions just begs for an indexed addressing:

```
incl    (%edi, %eax, 4)         # freq[i]++
```

This way you can also move the `movl ptrfreq, %edi` instruction outside of the loop (before the *l_freq:* label) since `%edi` no longer changes.